# Problem with OSM relation:restriction when mapping OSM data to GeoJSON

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, ogr2ogr

In OSM are mapped some restrictions, as for example turn restrictions. These are applied to specific node and to at least an origin linestring (**from**) and a destination linestring (**to**).

I used ogr2ogr to obtain GeoJSON files from OSM pbf file downloaded from geofabrik.
I obtained five GeoJSON (points, lines, multilinestring, multipolygons, and other_relations).
Restrictions, can be found in the other_relations GeoJSON.
Here I reported an example

```
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 1111372,
    "properties": {
        "osm_id": "1111372",
        "type": "restriction",
        "other_tags": "\"restriction\"=>\"only_right_turn\""
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "geometries": [
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    11.2111972,
                    43.798499
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        11.2111562,
                        43.7985113
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2111972,
                        43.798499
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        11.2119847,
                        43.7986283
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2119168,
                        43.798614
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2118678,
                        43.7985986
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2117438,
                        43.7985551
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2116203,
                        43.7985203
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2115082,
                        43.7985002
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2114085,
                        43.7984931
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2113254,
                        43.7984888
                    ],
                    [
                        11.2111972,
                        43.798499
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I cannot find a solution to understand **from** which way and **to** which way the restriction is applied.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: It looks like the information you are searching for isn't present in the GeoJSON.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there are some options to use in order to include such info into the GeoJSON obtained with ogr2ogr